# How to write down degrees, minutes seconds in excel and convert them later to decimal degrees?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, coordinates

I have the locations of many points as degrees, minutes, seconds (Handwritten). How to insert these locations in excel and convert them later to decimal degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter your location data in 3 columns, A, B, C, the decimal degree is simply =A2+B2/60+C2/3600, where A = degrees, B = minutes, C = seconds.